# Checking cross-validation accuracy using regression

Tags: cross-validation, nonlinear-regression, accuracy

I want to empirically check cross-validation accuracy. That is, I am trying to check and better understand bias and variance in the estimation of error by varying the $K$s in K-Fold. For this purpose I need the *real* error of the model.

My idea is to use this function:

$$y(x) = \log{x}\sin{x} + 1/10N(0, 2\log(1+x)) + 2\cos{x}$$

to generate a random sample $D$ and then use cross-validation techniques for this sample $D$ and a regression model (simply a polynomial of degree $10$) to estimate the error. Then I could compare this to the error obtained by using the model to a very large sample generated from the function above.

I would do this because for example neural networks are computationally expensive. Is this approach reasonable?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `use a regression model to estimate the error. Then I could compare this to the error obtained by using the model to a very large sample...`, preferably with a concrete example?  Are you evaluating the error of the regression model?

Comment: @user99889 Something like `model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 6))`

Comment: So you would generate sample *D*, fit `model` on the sample, and then see the error `e = (model(D)-y_truth)^2`--where y_truth is *y(x)* in your original question. You would also estimate this error using cross validation to get `ecv` and then you would compare `e` with `ecv`?

Comment: @user99889 yes, that is the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is reasonable for assessing CV error in this particular case, without generalization to other models and datasets.  This method is applied in [ISLR](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf) and shown in Fig 5.6.

[image]

Here the authors *simulate* data and therefore can compute the *true* MSE.  One thing they show is that even though CV might not be equal to the true error (it's not unbiased---in this case, it underestimates the error), the CV estimate tends to be around a minimum when the true error is also around a minimum, which is why CV is very good for model selection.

Keep in mind however that your "check" of cross validation would only be valid for this particular dataset/model pair.  I guess I am still not sure what your goal is with respect to the neural network---perhaps to see which K is best using this synthetic data so then you know which one to use for your neural network, without having to essentially do a search over K using the neural network.  I don't think this procedure will give you this information.

In practice, K in the range 5 to 10 is commonly used. Consider the extremes: LOOCV leads to high variance and low bias of the estimate; very large K leads to high variance of the estimator (Imagine with an N observation dataset choosing K=N-1. For each fold, you then train on only one case and, unless your data is very bland, get a completely different estimator for each one) along with lower variance and higher bias of the estimate. K equal to 5 to 10 seems to be a good settling point.  To quote ISLR:

> as these values have been shown empirically to yield test error rate estimates that suffer neither from excessively high bias nor from very high variance